# Unable to move MemSQL Community Edition to new EC2 host with AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, singlestore

I have attempted to bring up my MemSQL, Community Edition, single-host cluster on a different EC2 host (with a different ip addr) from a full AMI image.  I have attempted the recommendations in [How to change IP addresses of memsql nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722282/how-to-change-ip-addresses-of-memsql-nodes) yet I cannot get it to work.  I can connect to MemSQL-ops via the web interface.  It shows a MASTER AGGREGATOR on the new local host with the new ip address.  However, it is still looking for the cluster at the old ip address.  I have attempted to unmonitor/monitor both the MASTER AGGREGATOR and the LEAF.
An output of the commands and errors is below:

```
10.0.0.232: ~$ sudo memsql-ops memsql-start --all
Starting cluster
MemSQL node BD090F1 failed to start: Failed to connect to MemSQL node BD090F1: No error in tracelog
10.0.0.232: ~$ sudo memsql-ops memsql-unmonitor
 Index  ID       Agent Id  Process State  Cluster State  Role    Host        Port  Version
 1      6A15216  Aec14b6   NOT RUNNING    CONNECTED      MASTER  10.0.0.181  3306  5.5.11
 2      BD090F1  Aec14b6   NOT RUNNING    CONNECTED      LEAF    10.0.0.181  3307  5.5.11
Select an option: 2
Would you additionally like to remove the leaf node from the MemSQL cluster? (You can specify this behavior with --remove-leaf.) [y/n] n
2017-01-18 15:38:29: J5ba705 [INFO] Stopping monitoring for MemSQL node BD090F1
2017-01-18 15:38:29: J5ba705 [INFO] No longer monitoring MemSQL node BD090F1
10.0.0.232: ~$ sudo memsql-ops memsql-monitor -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
2017-01-18 15:38:53: Jb697d2 [INFO] Monitoring MemSQL node at 10.0.0.232:3307
2017-01-18 15:38:55: Jb697d2 [ERROR] Failed to connect to MemSQL at 10.0.0.232:3307:
10.0.0.232: ~$ sudo memsql-ops memsql-monitor -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
2017-01-18 15:40:32: J18a2de [INFO] Monitoring MemSQL node at 10.0.0.232:3306
2017-01-18 15:40:32: J18a2de [ERROR] Failed to connect to MemSQL at 10.0.0.232:3306:
10.0.0.232: ~$ sudo memsql-ops memsql-start --all
Starting cluster
MemSQL node 6A15216 failed to start: Failed to connect to MemSQL node 6A15216: No error in tracelog
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like memsql ops is using the ip address of the memsql-ops agent. To fix it, you will need an extra step:

- memsql-ops memsql-unmonitor  for each memsql node
- sudo memsql-ops stop
- sudo memsql-ops start --host 127.0.0.1
- memsql-ops memsql-monitor [-h 127.0.0.1] [-P PORT] for each memsql node